# Brainstorm! cfqueryparam-strength validation w/o the tag

Tags: sql, security, coldfusion, xss, sql-injection

Background: A colleague of mine developed a bunch of ColdFusion applications built on a common home-grown framework. There are ~100 applications each with their own databases.

Problem: I think it's impossible to secure queries in this architecture using cfqueryparam. Perhaps there's a creative alternative that I'm not thinking of, so I wanted a second opinion before I gave up.

**Database Layer**

```
string function generateCriteria ( struct criteriaStructure ) {
    var criteriaSQL = '';
    if( structKeyExists(criteriaStructure,'ID') 
        and isValid('integer',criteriaStructure.ID) 
    ) { 
      criteriaSQL &= "AND ID = '#criteriaStructure.ID#'"; 
    }
    if( structKeyExists(criteriaStructure,'NAME') 
        and isValid('string',criteriaStructure.NAME) 
    ) { 
      criteriaSQL &= "AND NAME = '#criteriaStructure.NAME#'"; 
    }
    if( structKeyExists(criteriaStructure,'FORIEGN_ID') 
        and isValid('integer',criteriaStructure.NAME) 
    ) { 
      criteriaSQL &= "AND FORIEGN_ID = '#criteriaStructure.FORIEGN_ID#'"; 
    }
    return criteriaSQL;
}

query function selectQuery( struct criteriaStructure ) {
    <cfquery>
        select * from table
        where 1=1 AND #generateCriteria(criteriaStructure)#
    </cfquery>
    return query;
}

void function deleteQuery( struct criteriaStructure ) {
    <cfquery>
        delete from table
        where 1=1 AND #generateCriteria(criteriaStructure)#
    </cfquery>
}

void function writeQuery( struct objectStructure, struct criteriaStructure ) {    
    <cfquery>
        update table 
        set fields based on objectStructure
        where 1=1 AND #generateCriteria(criteriaStructure)#
    </cfquery>
}
```

**Possible Web Layer Code**

```
// get some records
criteriaStructure.FORIEGN_ID = safeText(form.foriegnKey);
getRecordsWithCertainForeignKey = selectQuery( criteriaStructure );

// update some records
criteriaStructure.NAME = safeText(url.oldName);
objectStructure.NAME = safeText(url.newName);
writeQuery( objectStructure, criteriaStructure );
```

CF won't allow me to place cfqueryparam tags inside the generateCriteria function since it isn't within a cfquery block. But I really don't want to copy the criteria inside each query function! The whole point of having a separate function is that criteria definitions can be added in one central place.

So my SQL security relies on magic quotes plus basic "are you an integer?" validation in the generateCriteria function. Form and URL input is also run through a malicious code stripping function that's an older version of Nathan Dintenfass's SafeText function: http://www.cflib.org/udf/SafeText.

Are there other things I could do? I'd really like to use cfqueryparam, but don't know how. Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: You could alter the `generateCriteria` function to return an Array of Structs. These contains the conditions `AND`/`OR`; `=`/`LIKE`; the param type and of course the value.

Comment: huh. then loop over the array, inserting cfqueryparam based on each criteria's type... that's a good idea.

Comment: If you use a cfscript query (via `new query()`), you can pass the query object into `generateCriteria` and use the `addParam` method to add parameters to the query. You'll have to update the SQL for each as well, like this: `qry.setSQL( qry.getSQL() & "AND id = :id" )`.

Comment: @Bardware: You'd also have to store the start and end of each clause in addition to the type, value, and condition. For example: criteria.name = "category_label"; criteria.value = "obelisks"; criteria.type = "string"; criteria.operator = "eq"; criteria.clause_start = "AND CATEGORY_ID IN (SELECT LABEL FROM CATEGORY WHERE LABEL = "; criteria.clause_end = ")";

Comment: This looks exactly like what DataMgr.cfc does, except it uses cfqueryparam, doesn't use SELECT * and has a host of other handy features.